# Is it possible to implement only XSS prevention in Spring security and leave everything else open?

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security, xss

I'm working on a project where the OAuth2 implementation has not yet been consolidated, but I have been requested to investigate XSS prevention on the platform. Since the security concern is a known vulnerability, can Spring Security be in place to prevent XSS **only** and disable any form of authorization and authentication?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, though there may be some things that you will still want, like Spring Security's application firewall.

By default, `HttpSecurity` will add http basic, form login, CSRF protection, and various security headers, but these can all be configured. The following leaves only the `X-XSS-Protection` header in place:

```
@EnableWebSecurity
public class SecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {
    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) {
        http
            .csrf().disable()
            .headers()
                .defaultsDisabled()
                .xssProtection()
    }
}
```